# Subclipse not showing the SVN data in package explorer and team options not available

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, subversive

I installed completely from scratch adt latest version with Juno, and I installed the latest subclipse plug-in (1.10) from the update site. However, once everything is installed I am not able to see the SVN data in the package explorer and in the context menu on the file no team option is available.

How can I investigate what's happening behind? I have not been able to find anything helping in google.

Some information from suggestions below:

- I was having a previous installation of juno and I started from scratch in a new folder.
- I am using the same workspace as before.
- I have tried using subclipse alone, subversive alone and both installed at the same time.
- The folder in workspace is recognized by Tortoise in windows, no corruption on SVN folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not see the Share Project option in the Team menu, then I would guess the issue is that you are reusing an existing workspace and you had Subversive plugin, not Subclipse installed, and these projects were already connected to Subversive.  So the Eclipse framework thinks it is associated with Subversive, but that plugin is not available to add its options to the Team menu.

Create a new workspace is one option.  Install Subversive is another option.

UPDATE:

If you do see the Share Project option, then that is your answer.  You need to take that option to "connect" your project to your SCM plugin. Projects that are already in your workspace when you install a new SCM plugin do not get connected to your SCM automatically.  You have to take Team > Share Project to make the connection.

SOLUTION THAT WORKED:

For recognizing the existing installation of SVN you need to use Team > Share Project and then select the proper version control tool (SVN this case), automatically will associated SVN to the project.

Comment: I was having installed subclipse in the workspace. I tried all possibilities (subsclipse, subversion and both). None is working. Tortoise recognizes the folder as SVN.

Comment: Subversive is a different Eclipse SVN plugin. Read my answer again.

Comment: When I said Subversion it should have said "subversive". More concretely using juno update. I will update my question. Sorry for the wrong information.

Comment: I had the opposite problem: I had used Subclipse in the past and tried to use Subversive after an upgrade and nothing was working. In my case, the "Team" menu did not have any "Share..." option so I had to reinstall Subclipse. It would be great to get clarification on what will and will not work to switch Team providers in Eclipse.

Comment: The issue is what I described.  Eclipse stores the relationship between project and Team provider plugin so it knows what code to fire when events happen.  So if you want to change providers, you should first use Team > Disconnect while you have the "old" plugin installed, then install the new plugin and use Team > Share to connect it.

Comment: For me TortoiseSVN worked but most Subclipse options were missing after an update of Eclipse. The solution was to (re)select the menu option Team=>Share (which still existed). Then Eclipse recognized that the project already has been shared and somehow repaired the Subclipse settings for the project. With other words: the share action fixed the menu entries.